# Error in starting Ruby server on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The error I'm getting is the following:

> C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/m
>   ysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/my
>   sql2 (LoadError)
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-
>   mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in '
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-
>   mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in require'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-
>   mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in '
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/
>   bundler/runtime.rb:76:in require'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/
>   bundler/runtime.rb:76:in block (2 levels) in require'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/
>   bundler/runtime.rb:72:in each'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/
>   bundler/runtime.rb:72:in block in require'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/
>   bundler/runtime.rb:61:in each'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/
>   bundler/runtime.rb:61:in require'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/
>   bundler.rb:134:in require'
>               from D:/xampp/htdocs/RubyCms/config/application.rb:7:in '
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib
>   /rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in require'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib
>   /rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in block in server'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib
>   /rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in tap'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib
>   /rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in server'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib
>   /rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in run_command!'
>               from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib
>   /rails/commands.rb:17:in '
>               from bin/rails:4:in require'
>               from bin/rails:4:in '

I don't really know what's wrong.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Save ur gemfile.lock on desktop and try bundle update

Comment: please add the whole stacktrace with exception message to the question

Comment: I dont have this in my directory C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/m ysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I accidentally created a new Rails app with default database (sqlite3) but actually had mysql2 installed.

Check which database you installed and which one is required in the gemfile.